# Find position of a "word" in string and print N number of chars before and after the "word" in the string

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string stored in variable `text`:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit example amet"
```

How can I make Python look for the word `"example"` in the string and print it along with the 3 characters before and after it? For example, for above string it should print:

```
"it example am"
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get the index of the search term, then regular string slicing to get the word and everything on either side.

```
ex = 'example'
index = text.find(ex)
if index != -1:
    start = max(0, index - 3)
    finish = index + len(ex) + 3
    print(text[start:finish])
```

Comment: I get an error -     print(text[start:finish]); TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @ppsn works fine for me. are you sure you haven't replaced `text` with anything else ?

Comment: Nevermind! I only made a small mistake in my code, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) like so:

```
import re
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit example amet"
substr = re.findall(r'.{0,3}example.{0,3}', text)
print(substr[0])
# it example am
```

I am using `.{0,3}` (any character repeated 0 to 3 times, inclusive) rather than the more simple `.{3}` or `...` (both meaning any character repeated *exactly* 3 times) to avoid failing with error message `'IndexError: list index out of range'` for words closer than 3 characters from either the start or the end of the string (such as `Lorem` or `amet`).

Comment: [And now you have two problems.](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)  Simple and clever solution though.

Comment: Actually `.{0,3}` makes probably more sense (front and back) - what if word starts at character number 1 for instance?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Thank you for suggesting to use `.{0,3}` rather than the more simple `.{3}` or `...` to accommodate words at either end of the string. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit example amet"

word_list = text.split()

for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if word_list[i] == 'example' and i != 0 and i != len(word_list)-1:
        print (word_list[i-1][-2:]+" "+word_list[i]+" "+word_list[i+1][0:2])
    elif word_list[i] == 'example' and i != 0:
        print (word_list[i-1][-2:]+" "+word_list[i])
    elif word_list[i] == 'example' and i != len(word_list)-1:
        print (word_list[i]+" "+world_list[i+1][0:2])
```

You make a list from your string, space split().

You check for each word in the list, with conditions cause your request is not possible for the first and last word.

Then you print the two last char of preeceding, space, the word you look for, space, two first char or following.

output:

```
it example am
```

Comment: You can accept the answer :)

Comment: What if `word` would have a space in it? I feel like you assumed more than OP actually stated... (eg. Not `example`, but `example a`)

Comment: Word definition from google: a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence and typically shown with a space on either side when written or printed.

Yes, I am assuming the OP uses the definition found in the dictionary. But if you think I overinterpret, please support ;)

Comment: Words can also be delimited by punctuation.

Comment: The OP did not state anything about ponctuation. One may imagine he is interested by keeping it stuck to the preeceding word, or not. In any case you have a space between a ponctuation mark and the next word. At least in properly written  english.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the positions of substring using `str.index` and then fetch the sub-string using *string slicing* as:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit example amet"
search = "example"

try:
    k = text.index(search)  # Raises `ValueError` exception if 
                            # `search` text not present in `text`
    my_substring = text[max(k-3, 0): k+len(search)+3]
                       # ^ To handle if `k-3` is less then 0
    print("Desired result: {}".format(my_substring))
except ValueError:
    print("'{}' is not present in '{}'".format(search, text))
```